# Jackson exclude wrapping at specific class when using JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT

Tags: java, json, jackson

I came across a strange behavior when using Jackson with polymorphic behavior.
Let me explain with simple example, I have following classes:

Animal.java:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
@JsonSubTypes({ @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Dog.class, name = "dog"), 
                @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Cat.class, name = "cat") })
public class Animal {
    private String name;
}
```

Dog.java

```
public class Dog extends Animal {}
```

Cat.java

```
public class Cat extends Animal {}
```

Zoo.java

```
public class Zoo {
    private List<Animal> allAnimals;
    private Dog gaurdDog;

    // Getters and Setters
}
```

With Simple initialization this generate a following JSON:
{
    "allAnimals": [{
            "cat": { "name": "zazzy" }
        }, {
            "cat": { "name": "pus" }
        }, {
            "dog": { "name": "marley" }
        }
    ],
    "gaurdDog": {
        "dog": { "name": "rambo" }
    }
}
Here everything is as I expected. `dog` and `cat` are wrapped in object with name I specified when they are part of `Animal` `List`.

In cased of property `gaurdDog`, I want to exclude the wrapping and directly put all the parameters as below

```
...
    "gaurdDog": {
         "name": "rambo"
    }
...
```

How do I achieve that?

Basically I want to generate wrapper around `Dog` when it is part of `Animal` List.

Using: `Jackson 2.3.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Id.NONE`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.3.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonTypeInfo.Id.html#NONE) should work here. You need to annotate given property as below:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = Id.NONE)
private Dog gaurdDog;
```